# Scaling SVG images

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

For some reason when viewing an HTML page in different screens the page orientation and layout is different. It looks good on my HD tv but on my laptop screen it looks off. Here is my code, is there a better way to style the images? Im currently doing so using css.

Thanks!

*HTML* Ignore the script section.

```
<body bgcolor="000000">


<img id="manf" src="images/whitef.svg" alt="Body" />
<img id="man" src="images/bodyf.svg" alt="Body" />



<iframe id ="bre" src="images/icons/nresp.svg"frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id ="temp" src="images/icons/ntemp.svg"frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id ="stress" src="images/icons/nstress.svg"frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id ="loud" src="images/icons/nloud.svg"frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id ="g1" src="images/icons/ngas1.svg"frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id ="g2" src="images/icons/ngas2.svg"frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id ="alt" src="images/icons/nalt.svg"frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id ="shoe" src="images/icons/nshoes.svg"frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id ="cari" src="images/icons/ncari.svg"frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id ="heart" src="images/heartn.svg" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<p id ="Heart"> 100</p>
<p id ="RespirationR">200</p>
<p id="Temperature">300</p>
<p id="GSR">400</p>
<p id="Sound">500</p>


<p id="Gas1">600</p>
<p id="Gas2">700</p>
<p id="Altitude">800</p>
<p id="Weight">900</p>
<p id="Caribiner">000</p>
```

*CSS*

```
#main{
    position: absolute;
    left:-;
    top:0;
    z-index: 0;

}

#wheel1{
    position: absolute;
    left:1407px;
    top:428px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 30s infinite;


}

#wheel2{
    position: absolute;
    left:1590px;
    top:427px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 20s infinite;
}


#wheel3{
    position: absolute;
    left:1770px;
    top:427px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 15s infinite;


}

#person1{
    position: absolute;
    left:344px;
    top:778px;
    z-index: 1;


}
#person1T{
    position: absolute;
    left:344px;
    top:778px;
    z-index: 3;


}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate{
     0% {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    10% {-webkit-transform:rotate(36deg);}
    20% {-webkit-transform:rotate(72deg);}
    30% {-webkit-transform:rotate(108deg);}
    40% {-webkit-transform:rotate(144deg);}
    50% {-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);}
    60% {-webkit-transform:rotate(216deg);}
    70% {-webkit-transform:rotate(256deg);}
    80% {-webkit-transform:rotate(288deg);}
    90% {-webkit-transform:rotate(324deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}



}
```

JavaScript code

```js
 var myVar = setInterval(function () {loadJSON()}, 500);
    function loadJSON()
    {
       var data_file = "data/sensorData.json";
       var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
       try{
          // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari
          http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
       }catch (e){
          // Internet Explorer Browsers
          try{
             http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
          }catch (e) {
             try{
                http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
             }
          }
       }
       http_request.onreadystatechange  = function(){
          if (http_request.readyState == 4  )
          {
            // Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
    
            // jsonObj variable now contains the data structure and can
            // be accessed as jsonObj.name and jsonObj.country.
            // document.getElementById("Distance").innerHTML =  jsonObj.dist;
            document.getElementById("Temperature").innerHTML = jsonObj.temp;
            document.getElementById("Heart").innerHTML = jsonObj.heart;
            document.getElementById("RespirationR").innerHTML = jsonObj.respr;
            document.getElementById("Gas1").innerHTML = jsonObj.gas1;
            document.getElementById("Gas2").innerHTML = jsonObj.gas2;
            document.getElementById("Altitude").innerHTML = jsonObj.alti;
            document.getElementById("Weight").innerHTML = jsonObj.shoes;
            document.getElementById("GSR").innerHTML = jsonObj.gsr;
            document.getElementById("Sound").innerHTML = jsonObj.loud;
            document.getElementById("Caribiner").innerHTML = jsonObj.cari;
            
    
            if (jsonObj.heart>180) {
              var doc = document.getElementById("heart").contentDocument;
              // modify the style element's style
              doc.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.fill = "#FF0000";
            }else{
              var doc = document.getElementById("heart").contentDocument;
              doc.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.fill = "#00FF00";
    
            };
    
            if(jsonObj.respr>=55){
              var doc1=document.getElementById("bre").contentDocument;
              doc1.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.fill="#FF0000";
              // doc1.getElementById("ell").setAttribute("fill","FF0000");
            }
            else if (jsonObj.respr<55 && jsonObj.respr>25){
              var doc1=document.getElementById("bre").contentDocument;
              doc1.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.fill="#FFFF00";
    
            }
            else{
              var doc1=document.getElementById("bre").contentDocument;
              doc1.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.fill = "#00FF00";
              // doc1.getElementById("ell").setAttribute("fill","00FF00");
    
            };
    
    
            if(jsonObj.gas1>=20){
              var doc2=document.getElementById("g1").contentDocument;
              doc2.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.fill="#FF0000";
              // doc1.getElementById("ell").setAttribute("fill","FF0000");
            }
            else if (jsonObj.gas1<20 && jsonObj.gas1>10){
              var doc2=document.getElementById("g1").contentDocument;
              doc2.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.fill="#FFFF00";
    
            }
            else{
              var doc2=document.getElementById("g1").contentDocument;
              doc2.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.fill = "#00FF00";
              // doc1.getElementById("ell").setAttribute("fill","00FF00");
    
            };
    
            if(jsonObj.gas2>=80){
              var doc3=document.getElementById("g2").contentDocument;
              doc3.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.fill="#FF0000";
              // doc1.getElementById("ell").setAttribute("fill","FF0000");
            }
            else if (jsonObj.gas2<80 && jsonObj.gas2>20){
              var doc3=document.getElementById("g2").contentDocument;
              doc3.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.fill="#FFFF00";
    
            }
            else{
              var doc3=document.getElementById("g2").contentDocument;
              doc3.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.fill = "#00FF00";
              // doc1.getElementById("ell").setAttribute("fill","00FF00");
    
            };
    
            if (jsonObj.alti>3 && !jsonObj.cari) {
              var doc4 = document.getElementById("cari").contentDocument;
              // modify the style element's style
              doc4.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.fill = "#FFFF00";
            }else{
              var doc4 = document.getElementById("cari").contentDocument;
              doc4.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.fill = "#00FF00";
    
            };
    
            if (jsonObj.shoes) {
              var doc5 = document.getElementById("shoe").contentDocument;
              // modify the style element's style
              doc5.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.fill = "#00FF00";
            }else{
    
              var doc5 = document.getElementById("shoe").contentDocument;
              doc5.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.fill = "#FF0000";
    
            };
    
    
    
    
          }
       }
       http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
       http_request.send();
    }
```

Comment: As @Kaiido says, you may experience better results in object or img tags.

Comment: OP won't be able to style the SVGs if they are in an `<img>`.

Comment: What does "looks off" mean??  Perhaps you could check your code and make a snippet that works.  All the rules in your CSS seem to be for ids that don't appear anywhere in you HTML.  Until you fix that it is going to be hard for anyone to work out what needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Kaiido `<object>` and `<iframe>` are pretty similar when it comes to handling svg content.

Comment: @ErikDahlström Yes but their default styles are really different, OP could have less issues with object. As it was written when I commented, it was really difficult to understand the question though so only added this comment. + object has the pretty convenient `getSVGDocument()` method.

Comment: @Kaiido I'd encourage using `contentDocument` instead of `getSVGDocument`, in any case, both should work the same on iframe and object.

Comment: @ErikDahlström wow didn't know that iframe had the same `getSVGDocment` method ! Thanks. But I wonder why you would encourage `contentDocument` though. But maybe this isn't the place, since this question should be closed now, shouldn't it? Anyway, I do prefer include my svgs in `<svg>` elements :-)

Comment: See https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/struct.html#InterfaceGetSVGDocument (`getSVGDocument` is deprecated)